# Convert a list of lists to a structured pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, preprocessor

I am trying to convert the following data structure;

[image: Original structure]

To the format below in python 3;

[image: Output structure]

Comment: Dont post images of code or dataframe

Comment: What is the input ? Is it excel data? Python nested list?. It is very hard to debug from images

Comment: @ mad_ it is a Python nested list.

Answer (score 1):

if your data looks like:

```
array = [['PIN: 123 COD: 222 \n', 'LOA: 124 LOC: Sea \n'],
        ['PIN:456 COD:555 \n', 'LOA:678 LOC:Chi \n']]
```

You can do this:

**1 Step:** use regular expressions to parse your data, because it is string.

[see more about reg-exp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
raws=list()
for index in range(0,len(array)):    
    raws.append(re.findall(r'(PIN|COD|LOA|LOC): ?(\w+)', str(array[index])))
```

Output:

```
[[('PIN', '123'), ('COD', '222'), ('LOA', '124'), ('LOC', 'Sea')], [('PIN', '456'), ('COD', '555'), ('LOA', '678'), ('LOC', 'Chi')]]
```

**2 Step:** extract raw values and column names.

```
columns = np.array(raws)[0,:,0]
raws = np.array(raws)[:,:,1]
```

Output:

raws -

```
[['123' '222' '124' 'Sea']
 ['456' '555' '678' 'Chi']]
```

columns -

```
['PIN' 'COD' 'LOA' 'LOC']
```

**3 Step:** Now we can just create df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(raws, columns=columns)
```

Output:

```
   PIN  COD  LOA  LOC
0  123  222  124  Sea
1  456  555  678  Chi
```

Is it what you want?

I hope it helps, I'm not sure about your input format.

And don't forget import libraries! (I used pandas as pd, numpy as np, re).

**UPD: another way** I have created log file like you have:

```
array = open('example.log').readlines()
```

Output:

```
['PIN: 123 COD: 222 \n',
 'LOA: 124 LOC: Sea \n',
 'PIN: 12 COD: 322 \n',
 'LOA: 14 LOC: Se \n']
```

Then split by ' ' , drop '\n' and reshape:

```
raws = np.array([i.split(' ')[:-1] for i in array]).reshape(2, 4, 2)
```

In reshape, first number is raws count in your future dataframe, second - count of columns and last - you don't need to change. It won't works if you don't have whitespace between info and '\n' in each raw. If you don't, I will change an example.
Output:

```
array([[['PIN:', '123'],
        ['COD:', '222'],
        ['LOA:', '124'],
        ['LOC:', 'Sea']],

       [['PIN:', '12'],
        ['COD:', '322'],
        ['LOA:', '14'],
        ['LOC:', 'Se']]], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

And then take raws and columns:

```
columns = np.array(raws)[:,:,0][0]
raws = np.array(raws)[:,:,1]
```

Finally, create dataframe (and cat last symbol for columns):

```
pd.DataFrame(raws, columns=[i[:-1] for i in columns])
```

Output:

```
   PIN  COD  LOA  LOC
0  123  222  124  Sea
1   12  322   14   Se
```

If you have many log files, you can do that for each in for-loop, save each dataframe at array (example, array calls DF_array) and then use pd.concat to do one dataframe from array of dataframes.

```
pd.concat(DF_array)
```

If you need I can add an example.

**UPD:**
I have created a dir with log files and then make array with all files from PATH:

```
PATH = "logs_data/"
files = [PATH + i for i in os.listdir(PATH)]
```

Then do for-loop like in last update:

```
dfs = list()
for f in files:
    array = open(f).readlines()
    raws = np.array([i.split(' ')[:-1] for i in array]).reshape(len(array)/2, 4, 2)
    columns = np.array(raws)[:,:,0][0]
    raws = np.array(raws)[:,:,1]
    df = pd.DataFrame(raws, columns=[i[:-1] for i in columns])
    dfs.append(df)
result = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Output:

```
     PIN   COD    LOA  LOC
0    123   222    124  Sea
1     12   322     14   Se
2      1    32      4  Ses
0  15673  2324  13464  Sss
1  12452  3122  11234   Se
2     11   132      4  Ses
0    123   222    124  Sea
1     12   322     14   Se
2      1    32      4  Ses
```

Comment: Hi Anna! This is exactly what I am looking for unfortunately, when I run the for-loop, I am getting empty lists....[[],[],[],...]. I am sure I am match pattern is right. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @EdM are you getting it in this example or on your real data with modifications? And what python version do you have?

Comment: I have 3.6.4 & I am getting the empty returns (sets) on my real data. I cross checked the data type and its a list just as the toy example you provided and the structures are exactly the same.

Comment: @EdM Can you present a peace of real data?

Comment: Its protected data so I can't. But I put it together from parsing a bunch of .log files resulting into the format I showed here. How different would you approach it assuming each list inside the list came from a single .log file? In other ways if you had multiple .log files looking like this: PIN: 123 COD: 222 \n LOA: 124 LOC: Sea \n.....how would you loop through them and collect the data into a dataframe?

Comment: Did my previous response make sense?

Comment: @EdM unfortunately it is late in my country, I will think about this tomorrow. But it is strange if you have exactly the same format. Did you check my example with toy data and did it work? I'm sure there are many different ways to resolve your problem, I will try to do another way tomorrow.

Comment: OK Anna I understand & thanks! I will be waiting and yes I checked your example and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @EdM, Hi, I have added an example to do the same with log file, maybe it helps?

Comment: Hi Anna, just saw your update! Ok great I will try out this new solution & let you know. AND yes please add an example for-loop for multiple .log files including the pd.concat(df_array) part. That will go a long way Anna & thanks!

Comment: @EdM Hi, it's evening again, I will add an example through 8 hours = ) I hope it works on your data.

Comment: @EdM Hi, see new update for dir with log files. Does it work? Check that your log files have the same format (here is important whitespaces, because we use split ' ' to give array from string). And if you have the same columns count you don't need to change something in raws = np.array([i.split(' ')[:-1] for i in array]).reshape(len(array)/2, 4, 2), because I add len(array)/2 as number of raws.

Comment: Hi Anna, great!! Yes I just saw the update & can't wait to try it out. I will let you know soon as I try it out. Thanks a lot Anna!!!!

Comment: @EdM hi, have you tried to run the last update? Does it work on your data?

Comment: Hi Anna, I haven’t tried yet. Will try first thing tomorrow morning & let you know the outcome. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Anna, I ran it and got the following error: --->4 raws = np.array([i.split(' ')[:-1] for i in array]).reshape(len(array)/2,4,2)............TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @EdM Hi, please run this part as two raws to know where is the problem: raws = np.array([i.split(' ')[:-1] for i in array]) and raws = raws.reshape(len(array) / 2, 4, 2). And you can try to cast  int(len(array)/2).

Comment: If this helps with the coding -- The actual data has 9 of the 'Key: Value' pairs I gave in the dummy data. I am guessing that should affect the reshape part???

Comment: The bug is with the raws = raws.reshape(int(len(array)/2), 9, 2)....The valueError says - cannot reshape array of size 5 into shape(2,4,2)

Comment: @EdM last number in reshape is count of columns. So, if you have 9 pairs 'key: value', you should use .reshape(len(array)/2, 4, 9)

Comment: Hi Anna, the len(array) = 5 so when I run reshape numpy cannot reshape...what's the best at to align the reshape in this case....remember there are 9 key-pair values also...

Comment: @EdM If you can post the same example as your data, I can help. Because it depends on your data format (it will be better if I can see it). Or if you can't I will think about more automatically solution.

Comment: Hey Anna, can you email me please? -- "emddb@mst.edu"